# Response.Redirect disables back button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using using Response.Redirect to transfer control to another page. but this disables back navigation in the browser. What is alternative way to achieve this ?

Comment: `Response.Redirect` will not disable browser back button. Can you show your code? make sure that you are not using any JavaScript to disable back button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Response.Redirect` does not disable the back button by any means. Check it using web-console or put debug point on your page and check again. I think in your case the browser back button is working **but your page may be forcing it to redirect again to the second page**

Comment: Any suggestions on how to get the first page to STOP redirecting (again) when coming back to it using the browser's back button?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a client-side redirect.

[Here is code for 5 different ways to do this with JavaScript](http://ntt.cc/2008/01/21/5-ways-to-redirect-url-with-javascript.html)

I recommend the first one which is to set the `window.location.href` property in JS.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Server.Transfer()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: Server.Transfer is used to render the new page on current page, without changing url

Answer (score 0):

You must have added a javascript function somewhere in your project ( like MasterPage or parent page ) which is disabling back button and which is bad from user point of view , otherwise it isn't possible for browser's back button to get disabled on its own just because you have used response.redirect in your code -behind .